# Why can't I take close-up and night time pictures with my Nikon D3300?

Tags: macro, camera-settings, motion-blur

I'm learning how to properly use my new Nikon D3300, but there's two things that I don't quite understand.

First: Whenever I try to take close up pictures (of an eye, for example), the photo won't be taken! It's like, at 30cm or closer to an object, the camera won't take the picture.

Secondly: At night, I always use the night time setting, but my pictures are hard to be taken and usually came out blurry, or like if I've been in movement.

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: One question per question. The first though has nothing to do with your camera. It's a question about the lens you use.

Answer (score 5):

1. Each lens has a *Minimum Focus Distance*, it is often written on the lens. It is technically not able to focus below that distance, so you cannot take pictures from nearer. If you care to have a lens that has a very short such distance (like ~10 cm /4 inch), consider buying a *Macro* lens. Non-macro lenses often have 0.50 m/20 inch or 1.20 m/45 inch as minimum.
2. *There is not enough light*, so the camera tries to collect more light by taking a long exposure; if you move it even slightly during that time (or your subject moves), it will be blurry or smeared. You can either use a tripod (and static subjects), or set the camera to a higher ISO (but you will get more noise in the picture), or upgrade to a professional camera model. All those approaches have its limits though, too dark is simply too dark.

Comment: Thank you Aganju, this helped me, I'll try to do my best now :-)

Comment: Feel free to mark his answer as the correct one @lau3300.